# Laravel:sending mail from live server

Tags: php, laravel, email, server, laravel-5.3

i have all ok..working in the localhost..the mail is sending from localhost...but when i uploaded it in to the server mail is not coming and no exception is thrown too...here is my .env file code

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=mygmail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

and here is my controller code

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    //dd($data);


    $models = new User;
    $user=User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        /*'usertype' =>$data['usertype'],*/
        'status' => 0,

    ]);

    $use = array('name' => 'Admin');
    //$models->emailw = Auth::user()->email;
    $message_id = "";
    $name = "";
 Mail::send('emailMessage', $use, function ($m) use ($message_id,$name){

      $message_id = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();

       $name = DB::table('users')->select('name')->where('id','=',    $message_id)->pluck('name');   

       //$email = DB::table('users')->select('email')->where('id','=', $message_id)->pluck('email');
       $subject = "Id = ". $message_id . " name = " .$name[0]; 

      $m->to('mrbbangladesh2017@gmail.com')
        ->subject($subject);
  });
 return $user;

}
```

and here is my mail.php code

```
<?php

return [
        'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
        'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' =>  587,
        'from' => [
                   'address' => 'admin@mrbglobalbd.com',
                   'name' => 'Admin',
                  ],  

        'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
        'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
        'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
        'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

        ];
```

what i need to change here?

Comment: Have you checked your hosting that port for mail is not blocked by firewall (`port587`)?

Comment: Change the port no. to '465'

Comment: @KuKeC the port is open @K arun tried this port too still not working

Comment: Call `print_r(error_get_last())` after mail function is called to see what error you have. Or try using `MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail` instead of `MAIL_DRIVER=smtp`

Comment: for `sendmail` what port i should use? @KuKeC

Comment: Port 587 should be used, If don't work then try 465. Make sure your ports are not blocked by server.

Comment: this is the error in `post` method ..any solution? `Host: 119.148.19.213
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://119.148.19.213/officeapp/public/register
Cookie: 
X-Time: 1484719906384
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' `

Comment: Can you add printscreen of your error or whole text in question? It's hard to read errors in comments

Comment: here you can see the snapshot [link](https://www.sendspace.com/file/7ie7hw)

Answer (score 0):

There can be many things which can go wrong in your condition. I try to list all possible options:

1. Try port 465 instead of 587 as Gmail normally uses that one.
2. Check if port is blocked on your live server.
3. Login to your gmail account( mygmail@gmail.com ). Go to https://myaccount.google.com/security , Scroll down till bottom of page. In right you will see: Allow less secure apps, make sure that option is on.

*I hope it helps*

Comment: i have checked all the things you wrote...still not working